# Upload NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, react-native, postman

I'm stucked for more than one week with a problem. I'm trying to implement a **PDF upload** from mobile application created with **React-Native**, **API in NodeJs**, but I can't upload the pdf on the server, even with **Postman**. Here is the test I did following a tutorial from the net :

```
const multer = require('multer')

var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, "./uploads");
    },
    filename: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname);
    }
});

var upload = multer({
    storage: Storage
}).array("test", 0);

module.exports = {
    add_quotation: (req, res) => {

        let token = req.get('x-access-token')
        let decoded = jwt.decode(token);

        upload(req, res, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.end("Something went wrong!");
            }
            return res.end("File uploaded sucessfully!.");
        });

    }
}
```

Via Postman, I have this error :

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at createStrictSyntaxError (D:\Logiciels\wamp64\www\project\PFE\ReactNative\homi-back\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:157:10)
>       at parse (D:\Logiciels\wamp64\www\project\PFE\ReactNative\homi-back\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)
>       at D:\Logiciels\wamp64\www\project\PFE\ReactNative\homi-back\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:116:18
>       at invokeCallback (D:\Logiciels\wamp64\www\project\PFE\ReactNative\homi-back\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
>       at done (D:\Logiciels\wamp64\www\project\PFE\ReactNative\homi-back\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
>       at IncomingMessage.onEnd (D:\Logiciels\wamp64\www\project\PFE\ReactNative\homi-back\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
>       at emitNone (events.js:105:13)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1059:12)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

If someone could help me I would really appreciate !

Thanks in advance

Comment: See this might help you: http://sibeeshpassion.com/upload-files-or-images-to-server-using-node-js/

Comment: For uploading I use [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/). Also make most services don't support `PUT` method for uploading a file, in case you are doing that.